# How to debug ES6 NodeJS with WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, webstorm

I am trying to debug a nodejs ES6 server, even though I am using babel, I am getting this warning:

```
(node:17736) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. 
Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.

Process finished with exit code 9
```

Can someone help me fix this? I saw many questions about this, but they all seem old and are not working for newest versions of nodejs.

This is my configuration:

[image]

Comment: What is unclear about the warning? Are you facing any other issues?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it. How do I set it up correctly to be able to debug..

Comment: Issue similar to this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44834

Answer (score 4):

Seems the *Node.js* version `babel-node` is using doesn't accept `--debug-brk` option, and Webstorm can't detect what *Node.js* version is being used (normally it checks the version of *Node.js* chosen as **Node interpreter:** and uses the appropriate options when running).

Please select the **Node.js** executable instead of  `babel-node` there  and use `--require @babel/register` as **Node parameters:** in run configuration to get ES6 code compiled on-the-fly:

[image]

Of course, you need to make sure to install the corresponding modules and set up the .babelrc accordingly

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
  "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
  "@babel/register": "^7.4.0",
...
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

Using nodemon
Added a run/debug NPM configuration that runs this script `"dev": "nodemon"`

Answer (score 0):

Since Lena's answer won't work with async code, you will need to install `@babel/polyfill` and require it in the webstorm debug configuration together with the `babel-register`

```
--require @babel/register --require @babel/polyfill
```